# Is null terminate() handler allowed?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, terminate, undefined-behavior

In VC++7 if I do the following:

```
void myTerminate()
{
    cout << "In myTerminate()";
    abort();
}

int main( int, char** )
{
    set_terminate( &myTerminate );
    set_terminate( 0 );
    terminate();
    return 0;
}
```

the program behaves exactly as if `abort()` was called directly which is exactly what default `terminate()` handler does.

If I omit the `set_terminate( 0 );` statement my terminate handler is being called. So calling `set_terminate( 0 )` seems to have the effect of resetting the `terminate()` handler to default.

Is this behavior specific to VC++7 only? Won't the program run into undefined behavior if I call `set_terminate( 0 )` on some other implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking into the standard reveals the following:

```
terminate_handler set_terminate(terminate_handler f) throw();
```

> *1* Effects: Establishes the function
>   designated by f as the current handler
>   function ...  cut
>   ***2* Requires: f shall not be a null pointer**.
>       *3* Returns: The previous terminate_handler.

Seems to be non-standard.

Comment: So it is unspecified behavior, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's undefined behaviour. You need to store the previous handler and recover it explicitly.

Comment: @Alexander Gessler: to be precise, "unspecified behavior" != "undefined behavior", thus "no, it's undefined behavior".

Comment: (The difference is that "unspecified behavior" is used when the range of possible behaviors is limited. Some programs may tolerate any of the possible behaviors, hence unspecified behavior is not necessarily bad. Undefined Behavior never can be tolerated).

Comment: @MSalters - interesting distinction, does the standard put it in those terms?

Comment: Not directly. However, there is a note stating that the range of possible behaviors is usually provided. I.e. it is not always provided, but it always exists. Even more implictly, "crash&burn" is never part of that range. ISO C is more explicit, BTW.

Comment: @MSalters, @Manuel: Yes it does (1.3.5, 1.3.12, 1.3.13)